# cython function returns all values in a single cell after groupby apply

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, cython

I was looking to speed up processing of a groupby operation and while it now processes much faster, the resulting dataframe is not what I want.

Make MultiIndexed dataframe with some data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cython

data = np.round(np.random.randn(4, 3), 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['TOP'], ['A', 'B','C']]))
df
```

[image]

My cython function looks like this:

```
%load_ext cython
%%cython
import numpy as np

def func4(x):
    result = np.zeros([len(x)])
    for i in range(len(x)):
        result[i] = x[i][2] + x[i][1] - x[i][0]
    return result
```

And when I execute this function:

```
g = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: func4(x.to_numpy()))
```

I get a series with all values in one cell:

[image]

What I would like to get instead is an indexed series like this:

[image]

I am able to get the result I want if I convert result to a dataframe at the end of the function, but then the groupby + apply becomes slow again:

```
def func4(x):
    result = np.zeros([len(x)])
    for i in range(len(x)):
        result[i] = x[i][2] + x[i][1] - x[i][0]
    return pd.DataFrame(result)
```

**EDIT:**

You can use this to produce a large dataframe for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
import string
import cython

col = [f'{a}{b}{c}' for a,b,c in list(itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase[:20], repeat = 3))]
col1 = [str(i) for i in range(1, 10)] # change the 10 to a higher number to produce even more data
col2 = list(i for i in string.ascii_uppercase[:3])

all_keys = ['.'.join(i) for i in itertools.product(col, col1, col2)]
rng = pd.date_range(end=pd.Timestamp.today().date(), periods=6, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(len(rng), len(all_keys))), columns=all_keys, index=rng)

def top_key(x):
    split = x.split('.', 2)
    return f'{split[0]}.{split[1]}'

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(top_key(c), c) for c in df.columns])

print(len(df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()))
df.head(5)
```

UPDATE 2, performance of solutions:

Fastest, but resulting series has the issue described above.
[image]

Fastest with the correct result daatframe.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) is a tricky function because it can produce both aggregated and non-aggregated values (and it doesn't always choose correctly).

This is specifically an aggregate so [`groupby.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) should be used:

```
def func4(x):
    result = np.zeros([len(x)])
    for i in range(len(x)):
        result[i] = x[i][2] + x[i][1] - x[i][0]
    return result


g = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).aggregate(lambda x: func4(x.to_numpy()))
```

`g`:

```
   TOP
0  1.7
1  2.0
2  0.5
3 -1.1
```

(reproduceable with `np.random.seed(5)`)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
data = np.round(np.random.randn(4, 3), 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['TOP'], ['A', 'B', 'C']])
)
```

---

The slower way (seriously don't do this) would be to pass the index from `x` and reconstruct a `Series`:

```
def func4(x, idx):
    result = np.zeros([len(x)])
    for i in range(len(x)):
        result[i] = x[i][2] + x[i][1] - x[i][0]
    return pd.Series(result, index=idx)


g = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(lambda x: func4(x.to_numpy(), x.index))
```

`g`:

```
   TOP
0  1.7
1  2.0
2  0.5
3 -1.1
```

Comment: I tried it via aggregate on a dataframe with 200k columns and with apply it takes 7 seconds, and with aggregate it takes 39. My actual data is much bigger than that

Comment: strangely the last proposal with the slower way (passing the index) lands in the middle at 17 seconds. i will update my question with some results

Comment: I will wait a bit more to see if I get more replies, and then accept this answer as it gave me the fastest option for large dataframes

Comment: You don't have to accept my answer (or any answer). I really did only address the `pandas` portion of the question and not really the `cython` part. But I am glad you were able to get something that worked quickly and correctly.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but you did answer my question and actually even gave me a different version that ended up working fast enough and with correct outputs. Good enough for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Henry already answered the pandas part of your question, let me address the performance aspect. I don't really see the need for Cython here. As a rule of thumb, try to avoid loops over np.ndarrays whenever possible, i.e. use vectorized operations/functions instead of loops:

```py
def func4_py_no_loop(x):
    result = np.zeros(x.shape[0])
    result = x[:, 2] + x[:, 1] - x[:, 0]
    return result
```

However, in case you really want to use Cython, here a few key points for further performance improvements of your initial function:

- Type your loop variable `i` to reduce python overhead.
- Don't use `len` multiple times. It's a python function and thus, has python overhead. Instead, use the `.shape` attribute of the np.ndarray.
- Use [typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) for fast and efficient access to np.ndarray's underlying memory.
- Disable index checks by means of the [boundscheck directive](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#tuning-indexing-further).
- Similarly, you can disable checks for negative indices by the wraparound directive

```py
%%cython

cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound

@wraparound(False)
@boundscheck(False)
def func4_cy_loop(double[:, ::1] x):
    cdef int i, N = x.shape[0]
    cdef double[::1] result = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(N):
        result[i] = x[i, 2] + x[i, 1] - x[i, 0]
    return result
```

Timing all the functions for

```py
data = np.round(np.random.randn(20000, 3), 1)
```

with Henry's proposed solution yields:

```py
In [10]: %timeit df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).aggregate(lambda x: func4_cy_your_version(x.to_numpy()))
8.13 ms ± 160 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).aggregate(lambda x: func4_py_no_loop(x.to_numpy()))
1.18 ms ± 24.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).aggregate(lambda x: func4_cy_loop(x.to_numpy()))
1.3 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: yes indeed I just tried it via aggregate and it was much slower. let me try this now, thank you!

Comment: the apply version is still fastest from what I see. I updated my question above to include how to produce realistic test data